# Changing an element in existing Electron app

Tags: javascript, electron

I was tasked with changing an Electron React app that was written by someone who left the organization I work at. I've never used Electron, just a bit of node.js. Basically this app lets you create tables in a nice GUI and then export them as CSV file. Some table entries are hard-coded, and I need to change one of them. I didn't want to invest time in learning Electron from the ground up and just searched the app folder for the table entry and changed each occurence in various files (e.g. main.js, settings.js, bundle.js...) to the new value. This generally worked, but one field in the app remains unchanged, and I don't know how to find out where it's created in the code. I tried opening the browser developer tools, but pressing F12 does nothing. After a quick search I added this to the main html file:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.which === 123) {
        require('remote').getCurrentWindow().toggleDevTools();
    } else if (e.which === 116) {
        location.reload();
    }
});
</script>
```

But it does nothing. Also Ctrl+Shift+I does nothing. How can I change this last element? It might be a text field, or an image.. I've searched the app folder for image file endings but nothing of interest came up.

Comment: Do you know where the BrowserWindow is being created? If so, you can enable dev tools in the options passed to the BrowserWindow instance (https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md) and even open them by default with yourInstanceOfBrowserWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I wasn't successful though. E.g. there's a field called "security" which occurs in multiple places. In eclipse I searched and replaced each occurence of the word "security" with "derp". Then when I start the app, one field is still called "security", others are completely gone. There's a `dist` folder--could it be there's some sort of encoded, non-searchable file where the word occurs that was created by some sort of Electron compiler?

Comment: What are you doing in order to build the app?

Comment: Nothing, I didn't build it at all. It might be necessary..? At first I thought not, since changing some .js files already caused changes in the app

Comment: It may be that some of the files are built, do you have a readme at all? It may be worth looking at the scripts in package.json. Regardless, the built files ought to be a product of the source files.